# Need to capture 'elusive' Flash video from a site

Tags: video, browser-addons, flash, capture

I am trying to capture and download a Flash video from cooksillustrated.com site but all I get is a small swf 'shell/no video' file with Sothink Web Video downloader Firefox extension. NetVideoHunter is unable to capture it.

Is there a 'HollyGrail' web video capture utility which can get anything? It doesn't have to to be a Firefox extension. A desktop application is fine.

example: 
http://cooksillustrated.com/byissue/default.asp?docId=20628&selDate=151&currentVideo=y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a product called [Replay Media Catcher](http://download.cnet.com/Replay-Media-Catcher/3000-2168_4-10644938.html) which works very well.

Comment: It's actually Reply Video Catcher

Comment: dang.. it's Reply Media Catcher.

Comment: for the matter... it's Replay Media Catcher.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to try the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) Firefox addon. Open the plugin, load the page and start the video playing.

Somewhere there will be the request for the video file, usually with the extension `.flv`

It can help to save the headers to a text file, then open it in a text editor (so you can use it's text-search)

Another option is to let the video fully load, then prod around Firefox's cache directory for the file. ["How To Save Flash Video From Firefox Cache Folder"](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/11/19/how-to-save-flash-video-from-firefox-cache-folder/) explains this well:

> 1. Wait for the flash video loading completely, i.e. able to play MTV to the end
> 2. Open a new tab / window of Firefox and enter about:cache as an URL
> 3. Take note of the Firefox cache folder path specified in Cache Directory: and browse to this folder with Windows Explorer
> 4. Sort the cached files by file size and try to open the biggest file with Storm Codec-MPC or FlV Player. (The biggest file is likely to be the cached YouTube video)
>
> OK. If you want to know what those files in the Firefox cache folder exactly are, here we go:
>
> 1. While in the about:cache page, click the List Cache Entries link of the Disk cache device section
> 2. Press CTRL + F to search for Key: (URL) with the get_video keyword and also with the biggest Data Size: (YouTube doesn’t cache the flash video in FLV extension. For other flash video hosting site, you may save time by trying to search for .FLV extension).
> 3. Right-click the URL and select the Open Link In New Tab and refer to the File on Disk:

Answer (score 1):

The FlashGot and DownloadHelper Firefox extensions may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=296503

one user apparently developed something that runs well in IE. I left you with that original link just in case you run into some troubleshooting issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Hulu Downloader works fine with this website, but unfortunately, it's not free ($39.95).  But I find it's worth the cost because it has a nice user interface, basic video conversion features and works with many sites with video that cannot be captured with the standard Firefox add-in. It's available at http://www.getflv.net/hulu/.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use firebug for this purpose - there you can monitor network activity which flags all the files the system downloads and how long it takes, as soon as I see the video file, I grab the absolute URL and snag it with wget.

Comment: You can't use that method for certain streaming protocols like rtmp which the video I mentioned uses. These protocols were developed for better protection.